# Access link multiple records to same record

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a question about Microsoft Access 2010. I have the following tables:

Customers:

```
CustomerID  |  Name
123            John
243            Pete
567            John
```

Orders:

```
OrderID  |  CustomerID  |  Price
54332       123            80
43593       567            40
28493       243            60
58489       123            50
```

My customers 123 and 567 are actually the same, so i would like to update my table Orders to below:

```
OrderID  |  CustomerID  |  Price
54332       123            80
43593       123            40
28493       243            60
58489       123            50
```

Of course, this is a simplified version. I have to do this more than once, so is there a quick way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, update field CustomerID of the Order table. No big deal.

Comment: What do you mean with _I have to do this more than once_? Do you have to change many different CustomerIDs, or just one for many records?

Comment: I mean many different CustomerIDs.. And every week or so i need to exucute this, because often a new Customer is created, and then i want to redirect all the corresponding orders. I like to know if there is some way to join 123 and 567 to eachother, so access treats them as if they're the same

Comment: You need a query like `UPDATE Orders SET CustomerId = 123 WHERE CustomerId = 567`, but your database does not know what the original customer is, and which one's the duplicate. That means you need a form to provide those two numbers as variables. Furthermore: Don't forget to remove the duplicate from the Customer table.

Comment: Why are new duplicate customers being created?  It's probably a better idea to nip that process and minimize it from happening.  Then run a single update script to merge duplicates, and then you don't need to worry about it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping table, and regularly update all entries based on that mapping table:

```
OldID      |  NewID
567            123
```

And then:

```
UPDATE Orders o INNER JOIN MappingTable m ON m.OldID = o.CustomerID
SET o.CustomerID = m.NewID;

DELETE *
FROM Customers c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MappingTable m WHERE m.OldID = c.CustomerID);
```

If you fill the mapping table, and then execute these 2 queries, all the orders get adjusted and the duplicate customer gets deleted.